# Theorem 6.28 of Rudin's Functional Analysis

Tags: functional-analysis

1. I am trying for some time to prove theorem 6.28 of Functional
   Analysis by Rudin.The theorem says that if Ω is
   an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $Λ\in D^{'}(Ω)$,then there is      a family $\{g_a\}_{a\in \mathbb{Z}_+^n}$ in $C(Ω)$ such that:

   (a)$\forall\emptyset\neq K\subset Ω$,compact,the set $\{a\in \mathbb{Z}_+^n:supp(g_a)\cap K\neq\emptyset\}$is finite.
       (b)$Λ=\sum_{a\in\mathbb{Z}_+^n}{D^ag_a}$.

   Rudin's proof begins taking a sequence of compact cubes
   $(Q_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ and a sequence of open sets $(V_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that $\forall
       i\in\mathbb{N}$,$Q_i\subset V_i\subset Ω$,$Ω=\cup_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ $Q_i$,and $(Q_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$
   is locally finite in the sence that every compact subset of $Ω$
   intersects at most finitely many $Q_i$.We know that $\exists (φ_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ in $D(Ω)$ such that $supp(φ_i)\subset V_i$ and $φ_i\equiv 1$ in $Q_i$,$\forall i\in\mathbb{N}$.We use the $(φ_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ and we construct a locally finite partition of unity on Ω subordinate to the open cover $(V_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$,lets say $(ψ_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$.Obviously $\forall i\in\mathbb{N}$,$ψ_i\in D(Ω)$ with $supp(ψ_i)\subset V_i$.Let's now fix an $i\in\mathbb{N}$.Then $ψ_iΛ\in D^{'}(Ω)$ has compact support and if $N_i$ is the order of Λ and $\mathbb{Z_i^n}=\{a\in\mathbb{Z_+^n}:a\leq(N_i+2,....,N_i+2)\}$ then $\exists (f_{i,a})_{a\in\mathbb{Z_i^n}}$ in $C(Ω)$ with $supp(f_{i,a})\subset V_i$,$\forall a\in\mathbb{Z_i^n}$ and $ψ_iΛ=\sum_{a\in\mathbb{Z_i^n}}D^af_{i,a}$.We define $\forall a\in\mathbb{Z_+^n}\backslash\mathbb{Z_i^n},f_{i,a}\equiv 0$.Now if we fix an $a\in\mathbb{Z_+^n}$,we can define $g_a=\sum_{i\in\mathbb{N}}f_{i,a}$ on Ω.

   I now how to prοve that $\forall a \in\mathbb{Z}_+^n $,$g_a \in C(Ω)$.More precisely i have proven that $\forall \emptyset \neq K\subset Ω$,compact,the set $I=\{i\in \mathbb{N}:supp(f_{i,a})\cap K\neq\emptyset\}$ is finite and so $g_a\equiv\sum_{i\in I} f_{i,a}$ in $K$.The thing is that **i cannot prove part (a) of the theorem**.Can anyone help me?

Hint:i have an idea how to prove **(a)**,but to do so i must first
show(**if it's true**) that if $f,g\in C(Ω)$ such that $f\equiv g$ in
$K$ then $supp(f)\cap K=supp(g)\cap K$

Comment: You should probably explain what the heck you're talking about. Most people do not carry copies of that book around with them...

Comment: I second @DavidC.Ullrich: please edit your question to include the statement of the problem, otherwise your question will be put on hold.

Comment: this is my first post here so plz forgive me for any mistakes in notation!

Comment: Every compact $K\subset \Omega$ intersects only finitely many $V_i$ (you wrote that it intersects only finitely many $Q_i$, which is of course also true, but weaker). If $K\cap \operatorname{supp} g_a \neq \varnothing$, then $K\cap V_i \neq \varnothing$ for at least one $i$ such that $f_{i,a} \not\equiv 0$. But for each $i$, there are only finitely many $a$ such that $f_{i,a}\not\equiv 0$.

Comment: Daniel i cannot believe that all these days i read again and again that each compact K intersects finitely many $Q_i$ instead of $V_i$.The proof is obvious then.Thank you so much.So now we can say formally that if $a\in\mathbb{Z_+^n}$ then $supp(g_a)=\{\overline{x\in\Omega:g_a(x)\neq 0}\}=\{\overline{x\in\Omega:\sum_{i\in\mathbb{N}}f_{i,a}(x)\neq 0\}}=\overline{\cup_{i\in\mathbb{N}}\{x\in\Omega:f_{i,a}(x)\neq 0\}}=\cup_{i\in\mathbb{N}}supp(f_{i,a})$, where the next to last eauality holds because the family $\{x\in\Omega:f_{i,a}(x)\neq 0\}_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ is locally finite.

Comment: because the family $\{V_i\}_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ is locally finite and $\{x\in\Omega:f_{i,a}(x)\neq 0\}\subset V_i$.So $\emptyset\neq K\cap supp(g_a)=K\cap(\cup_{i\in\mathbb{N}}supp(f_{i,a}))=\cup_{i\in\mathbb{N}}(K\cap supp(f_{i,a}))\Leftrightarrow\exists i_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $K\cap supp(f_{i_0,a)\neq\emptyset}\neq\emptyset$.But this shows that the set $I=\{i\in\mathbb{N}:K\cap supp(f_{i,a})\neq\emptyset\}$ is not empty and hence it's finite because $\{V_i\}_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ is locally finite and $supp(f_{i,a})\subset V_i$,$\forall i\in\mathbb{N}$.Let's $i\in I$.

Comment: Then $supp(f_{i,a})\neq\emptyset\Rightarrow f_{i,a}\neq 0\Rightarrow a\in\mathbb{Z_i^n}$.This shows that $\{a\in\mathbb{Z_+^n}:K\cap supp(g_a)\neq\emptyset\}\subset\cup_{i\in I}Z_i^n$ which is FINITE!!

Comment: to be more accurate is $\overline{\{x\in\Omega:g_a(x)\neq 0\}}\subset\overline{\{x\in\Omega:\sum_{i\in\mathbb{N}}f_{i,a}(x)\neq 0\}}$